# Time to stable phase for the classic Susceptible-Infected-Susceptible epidemic model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

The classic Susceptible-Infected-Susceptible epidemic model is the following:

Each node is in one of the two states: Susceptible or Infected:

*Susceptible->Infected->Recovered*.

Let *s* and *i* respectively represent the percentage of susceptible and infected nodes, $\beta$ represent the infection rate, and $gamma$ represent the recover rate. The differential equation system for the model is:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{ds}{dt}=\gamma i - \beta s i \\
\dfrac{di}{dt}=\beta s i - \gamma i
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

with
\begin{equation}
s+i=1
\end{equation}

Given the value of $\beta$, $\gamma$, and the initial value of $i$ and $s$, we can numerical calculate the $s$, and $i$ as a function of $t$. Here is a typical result:

[image]

The epidemic spreading gradually progresses to a stable fraction of infected nodes in the end. My question what decides the time to progress to the stable state? That is how the epidemic parameters affect the length of $Ts$.

It would be create if there is an analytical equation for $Ts$. If it is not possible, it would be help as well if you could talk about how $Ts$ changes with other epidemic parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $s+i=1$ you have to solve only $\frac{ds}{dt} = \gamma(1-s)-\beta s(1-s)$ or
$\frac{ds}{\beta s^2 -(\gamma + \beta)s + \gamma} = dt$
which is
$F(s):=\frac{\log(s-1) - \log(\beta s - \gamma)}{\beta - \gamma} = t$.
Your time is then $F(s)-F(s_0) = T$ and probably you want $|\frac{ds}{dt}|$ small (say $<1/100$) to be in a region of stability.

Comment: Do you know how the value of $Ts$ qualitatively changes with the change of $\beta$ and $\gamma$. For example, when $\beta$ increases, or when $\gamma$ increases, how would $Ts$ change?

Comment: Is $Ts$ determined by $\beta/\gamma$?

Comment: I gave you the explicit formula.